# Using the results of FindPeak in FindFit

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

Using `FindPeak` on some datapoints, I have found the positions and values of likely Gaussian peaks which form the data. The format is `{x, y}` and the list generated by `FindPeak` is [here](http://pastebin.com/krPfi1UG). Now I wish to incorporate these values into a `FindFit` function somehow. I have seen it used like this before: `FindFit[MassSpecData, Model, IndependentVariable, Parameters] /. FindPeaks[MassSpecData, Gaussian]`, but this is somewhat vague. The model should be a sum of Gaussians, each corresponding to the peak values found.

[This is my attempt](http://pastebin.com/MDhkPHAQ)

```
dataconfig = {A[#], μ[#], σ[#]} & /@
   Range[Length@gausspeaksofdata3];
zerod = {A[#], 0, σ[#]} & /@ Range[Length@gausspeaksofdata3];
gaussian[A_, μ_, σ_, x_] =
  A^2 E^(-((x - μ)^2/(2 σ^2)));

FindFit[adjusteddata, {gaussian[##, x] & @@@ dataconfig // Total,
  gaussian[##] & @@@ zerod = Flatten@gausspeaksofdata3[[All, 2]], x} ,
  Flatten@dataconfig, x]
```

Comment: try putting code when possible in post. i almost missed it under a huge data list.

Comment: Your data has hundreds of peaks. Why not try a simpler problem with only a few peaks, get things working in that case, and then generalize?

Comment: I [gave an answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98251/13) to your privious similar question that make the whole tihng simpler.