# FullSimplify does freaky things with approximate Gaussians

Tags: bugs, simplifying-expressions

I was playing around with [Vitaliy Kaurov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/13/vitaliy-kaurov)'s [neat answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98251/531) to this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98198/531), and found something a bit unusual:

```
In[1]:= formula = 0.006101617526907695` + E^-(-7.` + x)^2 + 
           E^(-1.0000502772595525` (4.899999190832501` + x)^2) - 
           0.002006784176061687` x^2;

In[2]:= formula // FullSimplify
Out[2]= 0.00610162 - 0.00200678 x^2
```

Wait, what?

```
In[3]:= FullSimplify[E^-(-7.` + x)^2 + 
           E^(-1.0000502772595525` (4.899999190832501` + x)^2)]
Out[3]= 0.
```

I have to say this is not the result I expected at all.

```
In[4]:= FullSimplify[E^-(-7.` + x)^2]
Out[4]= 0.

In[5]:= FullSimplify[E^(-1.0000502772595525` (4.899999190832501` + x)^2)]
Out[5]= 0.
```

Well, at least it gets points for consistency.

```
In[6]:= FullSimplify[E^-(-7.` + x)]
Out[6]= 1096.63 E^-x

In[7]:= FullSimplify[E^-(-7.` + x)^3]
Out[7]= E^(-1. (-7. + x)^3)

In[8]:= FullSimplify[E^-(-7.` + x)^2.]
Out[8]= E^-(-7. + x)^2.

In[9]:= FullSimplify[E^-(-1.` + x)^2]
Out[9]= E^(-1. (-1. + x)^2)

In[10]:= FullSimplify[E^-(5.` + x)^2]
Out[10]= 0.
```

I gotta say, the last one was sort of a relief. Just to be sure, I'll plot something I never expected to plot:

```
Plot[{Boole[FullSimplify[E^(-(y + x)^2)] === 0.]}, {y, -7, 7}]
```

[image: my mind is blown]

FWIW, this is Mathematica 10.3.

Comment: Same results on V9 for your ... ehemm  .... relief

Comment: It behaves more as you might expect if you use rationals, i.e., `FullSimplify[E^-(5 + x)^2]`

Comment: This does *not* happen in V8.0.1 in OSX 10.10.5. It *does* happen in V10.0 in OSX 10.10.5

Comment: Nasty, this. Did you report this to WRI support?

Comment: @Szabolcs Why not a duplicate? It's the same situation, the lucky transformation is `TrigExpand /@ ExpandAll /@ ExpToTrig[expr]`.

Comment: @ilian Sorry, you're right.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I did indeed.

Comment: Yup, definitely a duplicate